# How to use an ngModel inside an ng-template which is repeated using *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor, angular-ngmodel, ng-template

I have a `ng-template` which is repeated using an *ngFor. I am passing additional data to the template from ngFor using `ngTemplateOutletContext`. With this data that I am passing to the template I am creating a dropdown list. I have [this stackblitg example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dpyyuk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) showing a code extract of what I have done.

**Data**

```
data = {
 row1_ID: {
  'article 1': 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text ',
  'article 2': 'Lorem Ipsum has been the industry standard dummy text ',
},
 row2_ID: {
  'article 1': 'aldlsadalskjd;asjsa;kdj dalskdjaslkjd',
  'article 2': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame',
 },
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let row of data | keyvalue">
   <ng-container 
       [ngTemplateOutlet]="OpRef2"
       [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ data: row.value, id: row.key }">
   </ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #OpRef2 let-data="data" let-id="id">
  <div class="row">
     <h2>Row ID: {{ id }}</h2>
     <select>  <!--Using ng model here doesnt work-->
        <option *ngFor="let article of data | keyvalue" [value]="article.key">
        {{ article.key }}
        </option>
     </select>
  <div>
  <!--I would like the contect of this do change based on what's selected in the dropdpwn but varaibles created in the context of ng-template are readonly hence nh-model doesnt work-->
  <div>{{ data['article 1'] }}</div>
</div>
```

Now based on the values selected in the dropdown I want the content below it to change. But since its a template, any varianle I create are readonly and can't be used in the `ngModel` for the `select`. Also I cant use an external variable list as the rows in the data property are fetched from an API and I cant be sure how many rows it would contain.

Is there any way of achiving this?

Answer (score 4):

If its only to be able to change de between articles you could do it without binding the ngModel to a property and accesing the ngModel value through a template variable.

It would be something like this.

```
<div class="row">
  ...
  <select ngModel #articleSelected="ngModel">
    ...
  </select>

  <div>
    <div>{{ data[articleSelected.value] }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Cheers

Comment: This worked as expected but it doesn't select the first item in the dropdown by default. Is it possible to select the frist entry in the list by default? I tried setting up the `selected` attribute on the first option element  by checking the index from ngFor but it doesn't work.

Comment: If you want such data binding other than article selection you need proper data binding. For that you can look into either of the other two answers by @Amer or me.

Comment: @BiJ In this simple example you could achieve it using `ngModel="article 1"`. But to do it dynamically with this data structure is bit more tricky. Since you are using objects keys as values, you'd have to assign a component class property to the global `Object` ref and then use `[ngModel]="objectRef.keys(data)[0]`. This looks kind of 'cheaty' to me, so a better option, if you can, is to refactor your data structure to use an array of article objects instead of relying on key:value pairs. `[ {title:'article 1', body: 'Lorem ....'}, {title: 'article 2', body: 'of the ...'} ]`

Answer (score 2):

Case is that you don't have a variable (reference object) to bind ngModel to.

I have done a simple implementation for you using a separate map as collection of reference. I used the data to create the map of references dynamically too.

Have a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t5fgl4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

HTML

```
  <ng-template #OpRef2 let-data="data" let-id="id">
    <div class="row">
      <h2>Row ID: {{ id }}</h2>
      <select [(ngModel)]="valueHolders.get(id).value">
        <!--Using ng model here doesnt work-->
        <option *ngFor="let article of data | keyvalue" [value]="article.key">
          {{ article.key }}
        </option>
      </select>
      <!--I would like the contect of this do change based on what's selected in the dropdpwn but varaibles created in the context of ng-template are readonly hence nh-model doesnt work-->
      <div>{{ data[valueHolders.get(id).value] }}</div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

TS

```
  valueHolders = new Map<string, ValueHolder>(); 

  createValueHoldersByData(){
    Object.keys(this.data).forEach(key=>{
      const valueHolder = new ValueHolder(key, Object.keys(this.data[key])[0]);
      this.valueHolders.set(key, valueHolder);
    }); 
  }

  export class ValueHolder{
    key: string;
    value: string;
    constructor(key: string, value: string){
      this.key = key;
      this.value = value;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a new property in your component class (e.g. `selectedData`) to hold the selected value from the dropdowns, then, binding the `ngModel` to it by `id`.

You can try something like the following:

```html
<!-- 
  In your component class, define a selectedData with and assign an empty object to it,
  to be used in the component's template: `selectedData = {};`
-->
<ng-template #OpRef2 let-data="data" let-id="id">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Row ID: {{ id }}</h2>
    <!-- Use ngModel to bind to the selected value -->
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedData[id]">
      <option *ngFor="let article of data | keyvalue" [value]="article.key">
        {{ article.key }}
      </option>
    </select>
    <div>
      <!-- Here we can use the selected[id] to bind to the selected value -->
      <div>{{ data[selectedData[id]] }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```